# Armazenando uma requisição em uma variável economizo recurso de servidor?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, cms

Usando o Wordpress vou precisar usar o link do artigo mais de uma vez, queria saber se armazenando o 'permalink' em uma variável economizo recurso do servidor, já que farei só uma requisição ao banco de dados ou há um gasto para processar isso que não compense?

Ex:

```
$post_url = get_permalink();
```

// Para pegar a URL e armazenar em uma variavel

```
echo $post_url;
```

// Para usa-lá

PS: Vou usar o link 4 vezes.

Answer (score 2):

Sem sombra de dúvida vocẽ vai reduzir as chamadas ao banco e aos objetos do TheLoop utilizando uma variável, e haverá sim economia de processamento/recurso do servidor. Apesar dessa economia ser pouca, qualquer economia é bem vinda, ainda mais com um código limpo como esse (IMO).